# Android studio multi dex error while executing packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex task

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-build, android-multidex

I am implementing multi dex for my project. I am able to compile the code afer implementing multidex but while running the project i am getting below mentioned error while executing packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex task.
Error:Execution failed for task ':appname:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class

dependencies list : -

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':slidingMenu')
    compile project(':androidPullToRefresh')
    compile project(':googlePlayServices')
    compile project(':caldroid')
    compile files('libs/admsAppLibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/xtify-android-sdk-2.4.jar')
    compile project(':clusterkraf')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-multidex.jar')
}
```

Below is my project structure.

library A contains my application class. In which i have implemented multidex.
Library B and library C depends on library A
My launch project D depends on library B and Library C. Library D android menifest i have defined the  application class which is available in library A.

Comment: show logcat please to determinate error

Comment: @Aspicas there is no logcat log as it is compile time error ...

Comment: yes, but it's always reports logcat

Comment: error is obvious ... `android-support-multidex.jar` is used more than once ... please do some research before askinging

Comment: @Selvin I know error but I need to know on what library it's the problem to give he/she a good solution.

Comment: Updated the question with project structure. Hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add play service library in build.gradle add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` in dependences

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

if there are conflict add

```
  android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
.....

    dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
.....
}
```

in the android block

Comment: Due to firewall issue i will not be able to use maven. All the dependencies are local. preDexLibraries option  does not help. :(

Comment: @HariSoni you have implemented multiple dependency as far as i understand you have added dependency of A -> B & C and B & C ->D which is creating a the problem

Comment: If possible use A -> B  , B->C C->D that will work smoothly and declare all the lib in the main project or i mean the main app

Comment: It’s an old code base and code is tightly coupled due to that changing project structure will be a challenging task. Why it is not happening for my other libraries ? I have around 8 libraries.

Comment: :) Keep a backup of your project and just try what i mentioned in comment it will not create problem i guess ,since the dependency of A library will be available to C via B lib

Comment: The problem may also occur because the same lib you are using in B and C and it is creating multiple dex during compiling

Comment: I tried changing the dependency from (A to B and C) and D to (B and C) to A to B , B to C and C to D. Still i am getting the same error. :(
Error:Execution failed for task ':appname:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79938/discussion-between-auto-droid--and-hari-soni).